# Search on my site without MySQL

Tags: php, html, search

I want to create a search on my website without MySQL.

I have a code, but it searches only in one file

```
$query = $_GET["q"];
include "date-list.php";
$filename = "news/". $news ."/lang.php";
$searchfor = "$query";
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
if(strpos($file, $searchfor)) 
{
echo "News found found";
}
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: assuming you're using PHP and outputting HTML / PHP data, then you could possibly use `file_get_contents` to load a file and then search the string that that generated. But note that it would also search the PHP elements of a PHP file, so what you really want to do is to start using output buffering, or possibly Curl... ?

Comment: ^`file_get_contents` also accept wrappers in case curl unavailable. But indeed needs `allow_url_fopen` to be enabled. And, xpath might help alot in this case.

Comment: I only can use this code for one file, but I have a lot of lang files and I need to search them all  `<?php

$query = $_GET["q"];
include "date-list.php";
$filename = "news/". $news ."/lang.php";
$searchfor = "$query";
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
if(strpos($file, $searchfor)) 
{
   echo "News found found";
}

?>` date-list contains `<?php
$news = "160702";
$news = "160701";
$news = "160630";
$news = "160629";
$news = "160628";
?>`

Answer (score 1):

> but it searches only in one file

Just loop over all files.

Wrap it to a function, so you won't need to loop to all files.

```
function wordFoundOnLangFiles($filename, $query) {
    $filename = "news/". $filename."/lang.php";
    $searchfor = "$query";
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);

    return strpos($file, $searchfor !== false) ? true : false;
}
```

Create an array containing existing lang folder name, such as

```
$lang = ['en', 'de', 'ru', 'ja', 'ko',];
```

If those folders is created dynamically, you could use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) or one with class [`DirectoryIterator`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

Begin loop

```
function wordFoundOnLangFiles($filename, $query) {
    $filename = "news/". $filename."/lang.php";
    $searchfor = "$query";
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);

    return strpos($file, $searchfor !== false) ? true : false;
}

$lang = ['en', 'de', 'ru', 'ja', 'ko',];

foreach ($lang as $folder) {
    if (wordFoundOnLangFiles($folder, $query)) {
        echo "Word found";
    }
}
```